# How to find the flux integral if the vector field is given in cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, cylindrical-coordinates, divergence-theorem

I'm given the following vector field equation which is in cylindrical form:
$$\vec{D} = \rho^4 \hat{\rho}$$

I want to find the flux through the surface of two cylinders which are both centered at the origin, of radius $1$ and $4$ respectively from $z = 0$ to $z = 6$. I need to find the flux in two ways. The first using surface integrals, and the second using he divergence theorem. I know how to do this if the vector field was given in cartesian form, but I have no idea how to do it when given in cylindrical form, since I don't know how to do the dot product in cylindrical coordinates.

I tried converting the vector function to cartesian, but it gave me some messy vector field that doesn't look right at all.

The picture for the question [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRqnO.png).

Comment: You're in luck - the normal vector for a cylinder is just $\hat{\rho}$

Comment: How can this be used to solve the problem? If my vector field is ρ^4 and the normal is ρ, I still need to get the dot product between the two, which I don't know how to do in cylindrical. Also, shouldn't the normal be <ρ,Θ,0>?Wouldn't <ρ,0,0> point in the positive x direction by the magnitude of ρ?

Comment: you don't need a coordinate representation to take a dot product - the dot product of any vector with itself will be its magnitude squared (i.e. $\hat{u}\cdot\hat{u} = 1$)

Comment: So in this specific case, the dot product of ρ and ρ^4 would be (ρ^5)^2?

Comment: $\rho^4$ is not a vector, you cannot take dot products with it

Comment: You said the normal vector is <ρ,0,0>, and I'm given <ρ^4,0,0> as the vector field, so wouldn't the dot product between <ρ,0,0> and <ρ^4,0,0> be (p^5), since the magnitude of <ρ^4,0,0> is ρ^4 and <ρ,0,0> is ρ ? If the vector was in cartesian, you would simply multiply  ρ^4 and  ρ to get  ρ^5.

Comment: I said no such thing. I'm telling you to avoid coordinate representation because it really only works for Cartesian (in other words every time you say $\hat{\rho} = \langle \rho , 0 , 0\rangle$ is just completely wrong). $\hat{\rho}$ is supposed to be a unit vector, anyway. It cannot have magnitude $\rho$

Comment: Ah sorry, for some reason I read it as $$\rho \hat{\rho}$$. So the dot product should simply be $$\rho^4$$ correct? and then from there, I can go on with the integral as usual, right?

Comment: That's it! But also recognize that on a cylinder $\rho$ is constant, so...

Comment: Ah true, so I got two surface equations, the first one with ρ being 1 and the other one being 4. One more question, if the surface wasn't a cylinder and the normal was something involving more than the ρ unit vector, how would you solve that? Do you have to convert the vector field to cartesian in such case? If you do have to convert it to cartesian, how would you do that? Would you use something like in the following link?http://www.uobabylon.edu.iq/eprints/paper_11_24775_76.pdf, 2.14 page 5

Comment: Sure, you could convert it to Cartesian using $$\rho\hat{\rho} = \langle x, y, 0 \rangle$$